# What causes a memory allocation even when this Func<> variable is null?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, allocation, benchmarkdotnet

Using BenchmarkDotNet's memory diagnoser, this code seems to allocate 12B even when called with `parameters` = `null`:

```csharp
public static void Usage(this ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, string area, string operation, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    Func<Dictionary<string, string>> function = null;
    if (parameters != null)
    {
        function = new Func<Dictionary<string, string>>(() =>
        {
            return parameters;
        });
    }
    logger.Usage(logLevel, area, operation, function);
}
```

If I remove the assignment to `function`, the allocation drops to 0.  When I look at the IL code I can see the following lines:

> IL_0000: newobj       instance void MIT.Logging.Infrastructure.LoggerExtensions/'<>c__DisplayClass0_0'::.ctor()
>
> IL_001f: newobj       instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, string>>::.ctor(object, native int)

The second line makes sense, it suppose to be conditional and in my specific case, the condition is NOT met.  But the first one I can't explain.

This is the benchmark method:

```csharp
[Benchmark]
public void Log_WithInfra_ExtensionMethodDirect_NoParameters()
{
    LoggerExtensions.Usage(_logger, LogLevel.Information, LogAreas.MainApplication.AreaName, LogAreas.MainApplication.Operations.Operation0, null);
}
```

This is the benchmark results:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Log_WithInfra_ExtensionMethodDirect_NoParameters | 8.441 ns | 18.732 ns | 1.027 ns | 0.0023 | 12 B |

It is stupid, it is not that important to my use case, but it drives me crazy.

Comment: Do you mean `parameters = null` and not `properties`?

Comment: @garfbradaz I assume so since there is no `properties`.  I corrected that in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the scope of `parameters` extends beyond the scope of your conditional, so the closure that captures it is created at the top level.

Simplifying your original code to this, for example:

```
public static void Usage(string area, string operation, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    Func<Dictionary<string, string>> function = null;

    if (parameters != null)
    {
        function = new Func<Dictionary<string, string>>(() =>
        {
            return parameters;
        });
    }
}
```

... the C# 1.0 equivalent looks like this:

```
   <>c__DisplayClass5_0 <>c__DisplayClass5_ = new <>c__DisplayClass5_0 ();
   <>c__DisplayClass5_.parameters = parameters;
   Func<Dictionary<string, string>> function = null;
   if (<>c__DisplayClass5_.parameters != null)
   {
        function = new Func<Dictionary<string, string>> (<>c__DisplayClass5_.<Usage>b__0);
   }
```

You can see that the closure is created, and its property is set, so that it can be used if needed anywhere in the function. To avoid this happening when your condition is not met, create a separate variable scoped locally to your `if` condition.

```
public static void Usage(string area, string operation, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    Func<Dictionary<string, string>> function = null;

    if (parameters != null)
    {
        var capturable = parameters;
        function = new Func<Dictionary<string, string>>(() =>
        {
            return capturable;
        });
    }
}
```

That changes your C# 1.0-equivalent code to:

```
   Func<Dictionary<string, string>> function = null;
   if (parameters != null)
   {
        <>c__DisplayClass5_0 <>c__DisplayClass5_ = new <>c__DisplayClass5_0 ();
        <>c__DisplayClass5_.capturable = parameters;
        function = new Func<Dictionary<string, string>> (<>c__DisplayClass5_.<Usage>b__0);
   }
```

Comment: See below, i've tried your suggestion and it seems that there is still memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this code:

```
    public static void Usage(this ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, string area, string operation, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        Func<Dictionary<string, string>> function = null;

        if (parameters == null)
        {
            var capturable = parameters;
            function = () => capturable;
        }

        logger.Usage(logLevel, area, operation, function);
    }
```

And it results in 44B of allocation.

What am i missing?

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Log_WithInfra_ExtensionMethodDirect_NoParameters | 11.83 ns | 4.657 ns | 0.255 ns | 0.0084 | 44 B |

Comment: Update your question with these details instead of adding an answer.

Comment: You changed `if (parameters != null)` to `if (parameters == null)`. If you're still testing this by passing in null parameters, then you're now going through the code path where the function and its closure get allocated.